# Will Xiaomi Mi band tracker work with Android 4.3?

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, fitness, xiaomi

Will the new Xiaomi Mi band (fitness tracker) work with Android 4.3? I know it says that it works with 4.4, but I also saw somewhere they said it won't work with 4.2.

Answer (score 1):

It is compatible with Xiaomi Redmi 1S Android 4.3. [Source](http://en.miui.com/thread-39105-1-1.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. it is compatible and I'm using with my Redmi 1S.

Comment: I didn't ask a question! I'm saying that I'm using the mi band with my Redmi 1S mobile which is running Android 4.3.