# Will Xiami Mi Band work on Redmi 1 with Android 4.2

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, xiaomi, fitness

The official line is that the Mi band requires Android 4.4 to work, but it has been tested on a [Redmi 1S running 4.3.](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/91637/102360)

So does anybody know whether it would also run on a Redmi 1 running 4.2? And if so, would there be any functionality losses?

I've checked here and the Xiaomi forums, but have been unable to find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went head and bought a Mi band. It didn't work with MIUI 5 running on Android 4.2, but it does work by updating the MIUI 6 on Android 4.4 (which is currently only available as a developer version).

[image: Android version]

[image: Mi fit]